# What's the name of this light airplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

The propeller of this light airplane almost looks like a triangle, so I'm interested in knowing its performance but I need help in identifying this plane because I don't even know her name.

[image]

Comment: I notice the word Hornet painted on the engine cowling.

Comment: It looks very concerned...

Comment: @Harper: It looks like the love child of [Robotnik](https://i2.wp.com/media.criticalhit.net//2019/04/og-dr-robotnik-eggman-sonic-x.jpg?w=850&ssl=1) and [Gru](https://statici.behindthevoiceactors.com/behindthevoiceactors/_img/chars/gru-despicable-me-3-47.2.jpg).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like the "Homebuilt Hornet, one-off wonder plane" on the cover of the March edition of the [Australian Sport Pilot Magazine](https://issuu.com/raaus/docs/sportpilot_mar19_final_web).

[image]

The article can be found on pages [34-37](https://issuu.com/raaus/docs/sportpilot_mar19_final_web/34).

Answer (score 8):

The aircraft is a Hornet, built as a one-off by Australian Colin Jamieson. The fuselage was made from two canoes, and it's powered by a 80hp Jabiru engine.

It featured in the [March edition](https://issuu.com/raaus/docs/sportpilot_mar19_final_web) of Australian Sport Pilot, where you can see more pictures and read something about it's history.

Comment: Two canoes, but no floats???

Comment: Wouldn't be the first case of [airplanes mixing with canoes](http://pineypaddlers.com/PP-Info/A-HTML/grumman-history/grummanhistory.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Jabiru in Australia seems to be engine manufacturer. They also supply propellers.
https://jabiru.net.au/propellers/

The prop pictured doesn't too much like the 2200 Wooden Laminate they offer for the 80 HP 2200 Aero Engine
https://jabiru.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/2200-Aero-Engine-Flyer.compressed.pdf

To my eye, it doesn't look triangular.

Comment: The prop blade on one side is quite a different angle than the prop blade on the other side.  It sort of suggests triangles.  Interesting aesthetic choice[...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lw4-vw4dceI)

Comment: The keading edge on both blades is forward on the spinner. I get the impression you have not seen a fixed prop in person. You should visit your local small airport and ask for a tour, to look at the planes up close.

Comment: Oh I actually thought the prop was tapered to reduce induce drag and increase efficiency #CrossRoads